# Unexpected identifier when using module.exports (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

I have the following module that I am using to connect to my database:

```
module.exports = {

    var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'rt', 'pw', {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3306,
      socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    })
}
```

and then in the main file,

```
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
```

But unfortunately this returns the following error:

```
/config/database.js:3
    var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'rt', 'pw', {
        ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/server.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

Am I using the `exports` functionality incorrectly? This error occurs for every object in the exports module.

EDIT: The following returns `cannot call method .authenticate of undefined`, even though the module seems to export without errors.

```
configDB.sequelize // connect to our database
  .authenticate()
  .complete(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
  })
```

Comment: Updated my answer to help clarify how the data is getting passed around.

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect syntax in your object literal.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish (specifically, how do you intend to use `configDB` in your main file?), but you've got some weird hybrid of object literal syntax and functional syntax going on.  Perhaps you want something like the following:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'rt', 'pw', {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,
  socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});
module.exports = sequelize;
```

Edit:
You're misunderstanding several fundamental things about how resources get stored and passed around in javascript, given your current structure it seems to me that you need to replace `database.sequelize` with `configDB`:

```
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
configDB
  .authenticate()
  .complete(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
  })
```

Comment: This seems to work, but when I reference the variable `sequelize` in the main file as `database.sequelize`, it returns an error (see the question for edit)